# Calling a batch file with arguments having quotes

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file test.bat and it takes 2 arguments from commandline.

```
Arg1 - "C:\work Area\"
Arg2 - "Hello politics="Hero Jack""
```

I have test.bat calling as

```
test.bat "C:\work Area\" "Hello politics="Hero Jack""
```

I want the second argument to be taken by bat file as `Hello politics="Hero Jack"`. I dont know how to call the test.bat with argument such that it happens so..
The second argument it takes is like `"Hello politics="Hero` and it discards the `Jack"`. Can you let me know what I am calling wrongly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is not possible to get it as one parameter

```
Arg2 - "Hello politics="Hero Jack""
```

It's because the paramter tokenizer is not very interested in carets.
It seems, that the tokenizer count only quotes.

The parser detects carets and can escape special characters like & > or <
But the tokenizer who split the line into the %1,%2 parameters use the rule.
A delimiter like  , ; =  starts a new parameter, this can only suppressed, if there is an unequal count of quotes before

```
test.bat """This is one param"
test.bat ""These are four params"
test.bat ^"This is also one param"
test.bat ^^"This is also one param"
```

But you can use a workaround, like

```
test.bat "C:\work Area\" "Hello politics=""Hero Jack""
```

This creates in %2 "Hello politics=""Hero Jack""
Then you can replace all double quotes with a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use a carat ^ as an escape character before each inside quote mark thusly:

```
test.bat "C:\work Area\" "Hello politics=^"Hero Jack^""
```

I hope that works for you.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

Okay, take 2.  Try wrapping the entire argument string in an extra pair of quotes:

```
test.bat ""C:\work Area\" "Hello politics="Hero Jack"""
```

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html